# FileUriExposedException when opening Email Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, uri

I'm getting a FileUriExposedException when trying to attach a Uri instance to the email intent as an attachment.

I have used the FileProvider pattern for handling of Camera Intent results, and its configured as below:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

However, when I try to attach the result Uri instance to the Email intent, I get unexpected results. See below (help would be greatly appreciated!):

```
final Uri pAttachment = getParentActivity().takeScreenshot();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,     new String[]{pEmailTo});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,   pSubject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,      Html.fromHtml(pBody));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,    pAttachment);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

pContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Stacktrace:

```
02-01 16:22:59.266 13989-14105/com.compuscan.vas.mycreditcheckmobile I/com.company.myapp.utils.EmailUtility: sendEmail: Support Ticket - 7258107843888828116
02-01 16:22:59.325 13989-14105/com.company.myapp I/com.company.myapp.utils.EmailUtility: sendEmail - failed: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.myapp/files/Pictures/screenshots_com.company.myapp/2018-02-01_16-21-52.031.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
02-01 16:22:59.329 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.myapp/files/Pictures/screenshots_com.company.myapp/2018-02-01_16-21-52.031.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
02-01 16:22:59.330 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1814)
02-01 16:22:59.331 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2389)
02-01 16:22:59.331 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
02-01 16:22:59.331 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8922)
02-01 16:22:59.333 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8907)
02-01 16:22:59.334 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
02-01 16:22:59.335 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4247)
02-01 16:22:59.336 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
02-01 16:22:59.336 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
02-01 16:22:59.337 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4206)
02-01 16:22:59.338 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
02-01 16:22:59.338 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4530)
02-01 16:22:59.339 13989-14105/com.company.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4498)
```

Comment: You have set up a `FileProvider`, but then you are not using it, based on your stack trace. You need to use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.

Furthermore, your Java code should not compile. `pAttachment` is shown as a `Uri`, and `Uri.fromFile()` does not take a `Uri` as a parameter.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, the pAttachment is supposed to be the parameters parsed as Intent.EXTRA_STREAM to the Email Intent, this was a Typo, checking out the FileProvider to get the Uri, will promptly give feedback

Comment: @CommonsWare, your help was sufficient, thanks: had to replace Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileInstance); with Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), authorities, fileInstance);